# How to merge multiple mp3 file using ffmpeg in android

Tags: android

I Want to Merge Two or more mp3 audio file using ffmpeg but i do not know how it implement in project.someone can give me tutorial or steps for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to merge multiple mp3 with custom meta:

`ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.mp3|input2.mp3|input3.mp3" -c:a copy [-metadata <key>=<value> ...] output.mp3`

If not specify metadata, it will copy metadata from first input file.

List of metadata options can be referenced in here: https://multimedia.cx/eggs/supplying-ffmpeg-with-metadata/

If you want to manage `ffmpeg` process (control success/failure, progress,...), you can use this library instead of implementing them by yourself: http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Comment: when to put above command in android project i don't know.please tell me

Comment: @ajaydhadhal see tutorial in `ffmpeg-android-java` I have mention above (it's explained in `Execute Binary` section)

Comment: @ajaydhadhal that command line is used in system commander (like cmd in window, or terminal in linux/mac). You can create a subprocess and call it from a Java program,  but you will have to implement managing that subprocess by yourself